# EditText cursor not visible

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText and the cursor is invisible. What can I do to show it? This is the EditText in XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_field"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/box_message" >
    <myApp.EditTextView
        android:id="@+id/text_editor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/send_side"
        android:hint="@string/Enter_message_Hint"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction"
        android:inputType="textShortMessage|textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:maxLength="1000"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:nextFocusRight="@+id/send_button"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:textSize="13sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

It is a custom EditText that has all 3 constructors.

```
public EditTextView(Context 
{
this(context, null);
}

public EditTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeset)
{
this(context, attributeset, 0);
}

public EditTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeset, int defStyle)
{
super(context, attributeset, defStyle);

//set onTouch listener.
}
```

I already tried without `android:textCursorDrawable="@null"` and it didn't work.

Comment: I used your code and I can see the cursor visible.Post your full xml file, may be background problem.

Answer (score 1):

May be because of your background color the cursor is not visible, try to make the gravity center due to which the cursor will be visible.

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Comment: That didn't work. I even set the background to green and it didn't work.

Comment: try to keep normal edittext, like only its height and width and gravity and see if its appearing. Then try to add your other attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted seems correct, so the Problem lies somewhere beyond this scope.
I had this problem once and it was due to the wrong context with which I called the constructor.
You can check if you actually call the Constructor with the right Application Context. I am afraid, though, that the Problem probably lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The cursor is displayed when `EditText`'s state is "focused". Make sure that the EditText is focusable. Try to add following attributes: `android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`. But I think that the problem can be in code of your custom `EditText`.

Answer (score 0):

Set some value to minWidth in xml 1,2,3.. Ex:minWidth="1px" to your EditText's xml

```
<myApp.EditTextView
minWidth="1px"
.
.
./>
```